# Symfony4.4: PUT processing is redirected

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have updated from Symfony 3.x to Symfony 4.4.16 and verified the operation.
When I press "Registration/change" to save the form, I am redirected to the form input screen.
What I want to do is save the entered information in the DB and display the top screen and success message.
Are there any changes you made?
When I tried `php bin/console router:match /admin/initialSetting --method=PUT`, it didn't seem to be a problem.

Controller

```php
     /*
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function initialSettingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $key = $request->query->get("key");
        $staff = $this->get("admin.staffService")->getStaffByUrlKey($key);

        // Create form
        $form = $this->createForm(InitialSettingType::class, $staff, array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("app_security_initialsetting", array("key" => $key)),
        ));
        // Show screen
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

     /*
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateInitialSettingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $key = $request->query->get("key");
        $staff = $this->get("admin.staffService")->getStaffByUrlKey($key);

        // Create Form
        $form = $this->createForm(InitialSettingType::class, $staff, array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("app_security_updateinitialsetting", array("key" => $key)),
        ));

        // Request processing
        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            // URL key clear, save
            $this->get("admin.staffService")->clearUrlKey($staff);
            $this->get("admin.staffService")->save($staff);
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Staff profile Initial settings have been completed.');
            // Login
            $this->autoLogin($staff);
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_admin_default_index'));
        } else {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Staff profile Initial settings could not be completed. Please check the input contents.');
        }
        // Show screen
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

services.yaml

```yaml
    app.form.type.initialSettingType:
      class: AppBundle\Form\Type\Staff\InitialSettingType
      arguments: [ "@service_container", "@admin.staff" ]
      tags:
          - { name: form.type }
   
    admin.staff:
      class: AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff
```

initialSetting.html.twig

```
        <div class="formGroup">
            {{ form_widget(form.submit, {label: "Registration/change", attr: {class: "btn"}}) }}
        </div>
```

**Postscript**
Looking at the code in the browser's development tools, I found that POST specified the method of the form.
Is there any lack of package updates?

```
<form name="initialSetting" method="post" action="/url/url/" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Version
sensio/framework-extra-bundle  v5.2.4
symfony/form                  v4.4.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to the code below and solved the problem.

```php
    /**
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     *
     * @Template("@AhiSpAdminBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function initialSettingAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->initialSettingAndUpdateAction($request);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Route("/initialSetting")
     *
     * @Template("@AhiSpAdminBundle/Security/initialSetting.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->initialSettingAndUpdateAction($request);
    }

    public function initialSettingAndUpdateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $key = $request->query->get("key");
        $staff = $this->get("admin.staffService")->getStaffByUrlKey($key);

        if (!$staff || $staff->getPassword()) {
            throw new HttpException(
                400,
                 The specified stuff prowl initialization URL does not exist or has expired.
                "\n".
                "Ask the administrator to reissue the URL."
            );
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(InitialSettingType::class, $staff, array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("ahi_sp_admin_security_update", array("key" => $key)),
        ));

        if ($request->isMethod('PUT')) {
            if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted() && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

                $this->get("admin.staffService")->clearUrlKey($staff);
                $this->get("admin.staffService")->save($staff);
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Staff profile Initial settings have been completed.');

                $this->autoLogin($staff);
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_default_index'));
            } else {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Staff profile Initial settings could not be completed. Please check the input contents.');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```